# VBA IF Then Else Looping issues, Confused on comparing values and logic

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement

I have gone crazy with vba projects around the house and helping my wife upping her reports to the next level.  I’m having troubles putting down to VBA what I’m thinking.  If anyone has felt my pain please shed some light on the actual script that would help me over this hump. Summary might be comparing cell value for certain text using InStr and if doesn't exist the appending characters to the right end. I can append and run thru one cycle of the loop but get confused with trying to write the logic I'm thinking.

Alittle background on the report: One row equals one reservation.  Within that row there is a column labeled “Nights”. This column is filtered for any reservation with more than “1” Night. Example: could be 3 nights, 6 nights, and 10 nights doesn’t matter. I have a macro that sorts these reservations and splits the one reservation into multiple rows totaling the number value in the “Nights” column. Basically, copying and inserting the rows next to each other. While this filtered is still applied (SpecialVisibleCells Only).  Now I have another column labeled “ResNumber”.  With 3, 6, or 10 rows split out the “ResNumber” column is the same number. I’m tasked with walking down this ‘ResNumber” column and appending a “-1” for the first row. A “-2” for the second reservation “-3” for the third and possibly a forth “-4” Until the last row of the copied for that one reservation group.  Then the cycle (loop) starts again on the next group or block of rows. Same procedure.

Dim lnrow As Integer
  Dim llrow As String
  Dim rownuml As Integer  'row checker
  Dim colnuml As String   'column checker
  Dim count As Integer
  Dim total As String 'Value of reservation's "Nights" column Offset(,17)
  Dim startnum As Integer 'Start number for counter
  Dim actcell As String 'Activecell
  startnum = 1
  With sh
     llrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).row
       If llrow = "" Then Exit Sub
         .Cells(2, 2).Resize(llrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

```
     For lnrow = 2 To llrow
     rownuml = ActiveCell.row
     colnuml = ActiveCell.Column
     total = ActiveCell.offset(, 17).Value

     For count = 1 To total
     rownuml = ActiveCell.row
     colnuml = ActiveCell.Column
     actcell = ActiveCell.Value

'Compares row 1 and checks resNumber value for "-1" if none exist it appends.
                   If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "-1") = 0 Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "-1"
                     Else
                     GoTo nexrow
                    End If

'Compares row 2 and checks resNumber value of above cell.
           If InStr(ActiveCell.offset(-1, 0).Value, "-1") = 0 Then
                      Resume Next
                    If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "-2") = 0 Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "-2"
                     GoTo nexrow
                    End If
```

'to jump out of loop          nexrow
    'ActiveCell moves one row down.
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
               rownuml = ActiveCell.row      'just checking row number
               colnuml = ActiveCell.Column   'just checking column number

'since 1st reservation is already in the DB startnum starts at # 1. The counter
                startnum = startnum + count
                Next count
                Next
        End With[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Times As Long, Counter As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim strNumber As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            strNumber = .Range("B" & i).Value

            Times = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B2:B" & LastRow), strNumber)

            If Times > 1 Then

                Counter = 1

                For y = 2 To LastRow

                    If strNumber = .Range("B" & y).Value Then

                        .Range("B" & y).Value = strNumber & " - " & Counter
                        .Range("D" & y).Value = 1
                        Counter = Counter + 1

                    End If

                Next y

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: You are a RockStar!!!  I was overthinking and overcomplicating this puzzle.  Thank you for taking the time.  I appreciate it.

Comment: If this answer fulfil your needs dont forget to vote it